# Git Source Tree errors with editing same files between multiple users

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Our team have started using Git with the Source Tree GUI, now the main issue we are having is that if any of us have been working on the same files and try and pull the commits we get errors.

So here is the scenario...

One of our dev's named 'John' edits a file and merges it to our main branch and pushes the changes to our server whilst one of our other dev's 'Simon' is also making changes to the same file.

Now when Simon tried to merge his branch he get's a conflict because that file has been edited on the live server.

If he discards the file then all of his changes will be lost.

What do you do in these situations whilst using Git?

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 1):

Simon need to stash his changes,  then checkout the branch which John just committed his changes, then get the changes out of the stash, then merge them to John's branch.

Answer (score -1):

`git pull --rebase origin <main-branch-name>` should be done first before merging his changes to main branch so that simon code will be up to date with main branch after that he needs to push his code to git and then he can merge his branch to main branch